# Serializing a class using XMLSerializer not showing fields C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have a class with two properties (which are generated from xsd using `xsd.exe`) and filling them and trying serialize them to xml with below code.

I'm able to get xml with elements in it but without its fields/elements which I have assigned

```
OrganizationDetail objOrgDet = new OrganizationDetail();
objOrg.IsDataLimitedSet =true;

Organization objOrg = new Organization();
objOrg.Orgainzation_Detail = objOrgDet;

XmlSerializer serailizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Organization));
StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();

serailizer.Serialize(strwritter, objOrg);
string xml = strwritter.ToString();
```

And the resulted xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Organization xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Organization_DETAIL xmlns="http://www.mismo.org/residential/2009/schemas" />
</Organization>
```

This doesn't have a field I have set.

Comment: You have to supply a value for your property `DataLimited`. I expect `IsDataLimitedSet` to be the one that is decorated with `XmlIgnore` to prevent it from showing up.

Comment: @rene yep I just found that, but why this System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute() annotation is being added any clue?

Comment: Yes, it is added, IIRC, for elements that have an xsi:nil="true" or have an minoccurs=0 and that map to a non-null type on your class. During deserialization the not nullable type will have its default value whether the Is[NameofProperty]Set is either true or false, depending on if the element was present in the payload or not.

Comment: Thanks @rene,  actually i have minoccurs=0 , i thought it meant  if value is not set it will not appeat in xml but if we set property it has to included,  so i would like to know what is the solution to get properties which have minOccurs=0 ?

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in comments, when we have `minOccurs=0` for elements we get annotation `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()` due to which even after filling the entity we cannot see the property

Solution:
Fields which have attribute minOccurs=0 when you run xsd.exe **for each element two properties are generated in class, one is the property and another is bool value for property with Suffix 'Specified'**

So for values to appear in xml while serialization , we need to enable Specified property of that element

eg:
As I have property `IsDataLimitedSet` there is also one more property named `IsDataLimitedSetSpecified` generated in class , so we need to set it to true

```
OrganizationDetail objOrgDet = new OrganizationDetail();
objOrg.IsDataLimitedSetSpecified =true;
objOrg.IsDataLimitedSet =true;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to fill the fields with data. The serializer is ignoring all fields which are not filled.